# Why the same code with WHILE doesn't work with FOR? [in R]

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, control-flow

I've faced interesting thing which I can't understand. I have a code in R:

```
i <-1
list_dset <- list()
while (i <= length(drs)) {
                        xx <- subset(dset, grepl(drs[i], flist))
                        xx <- as.data.frame(xx)
                        list_dset <-list(list_dset,xx)
                        i <- i+1
                        }
```

where:
'drs' is a vector of 2 elements; 
'dset' is a list of 24 elements; 
'flist' here I used as factors line for splitting 'dset' onto two parts of 12 elmtns; 
as result, I expect a list of two elements (which are data.frames) joined to a list.
The result is transformed 'dset', where first 12 elmnts joined to one DF and second 12 elmnts joined to another DF, both DFs joined to the 'list_dset'.

So the question is:
why this code works properly in WHILE control flow but doesn't with FOR?

FOR loop here:

```
i <-1
list_dset <- data.frame()
for (i in length(drs)) {
                         xx <- subset(dset, grepl(drs[i], flist))
                         xx <- as.data.frame(xx)
                         list_dset <-list(list_dset,xx)
                         }
```

Comment: eventually you want `for (i in 1:length(..))`

Comment: Or `for (i in seq_along(drs))` (slightly more robust in case of length 0), or more directly `for (x in drs)`

Comment: @Aurèle With `for (x in drs)` a part of the code have to be changed to: `grepl(x, flist)`

Comment: And to answer OP's original question, the problem is that `for (i in length(drs))` evaluates to `for (i in 2)`, which is not what is meant

Comment: Thanks! If I understand it correctly I need put a range instead of a number?